# How do I insert a column into a jagged array using LINQ / lambda?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, jagged-arrays

Although I can successfully force a column into my jagged array, can anyone help me find a better way of doing so using lambda expressions?

This code works, but there has to be a better way.  I tried converting each row into a list and then using List.Insert at the column number in hopes of converting back to an array, but this led to even less clean code.

I also tried using various combinations of `.Select()` and `.Where()` with no success.  My guess is that some kind of compound LINQ is the way to go, but I don't know how to do it.

Example `DataOut.Select(x => x.Select(y => y[columnindex] ... something ...`

```
 public object[][] DataOut;

 ...

 int newcol = GetColumnNumber("NewData");
 int insertioncol = GetColumnNumber("InsertionPoint");
 var newarr = DataOut.Select(x => x[newcol]).ToArray();
 var existingcol = DataOut.Select(x => x[insertioncol]).ToArray();

 if (newcol > insertioncol)
 {
     for (int j = newcol; j > insertioncol; j--)
     {
         DataOut.All(x => { x[j] = x[j-1]; return true; });
     }

     // Yikes, there has to be a better way to insert the data
     int c = 0;  
     DataOut.All(x => { x[insertioncol] = newarr[c]; c++;  return true; });
}
```

Again, this works fine and my data set is relatively small do I can go with it for the moment, but maybe I can make this scale-able and hopefully learn something too.

Comment: LINQ is not a suitable for this; it is a tool to query a collection. Better question might be to ask what is the best tool to use.

Comment: Have you considered using a dictionary; the key is your new element ID and the content is the new array. Some sample data might help with generating a specific answer.

Comment: The way to perform an operation for every item in a collection is to use a loop, generally either a `for` or `foreach` loop.  LINQ does not exist to perform an operation on every item in an array.  It has no *need* to do that *because that's what loops are for*.

Comment: You want to insert columns, and you've chosen a jagged array as your data container. I've no idea which way round you've oriented your jaggy but the mere fact that you've chosen to do this with arrays alarms me for a start, let alone that you're trying to do it with LINQ. Arrays shouldn't be a first choice data container for anyone wanting easy mid-point-insertion. LINQ too often seems to be regarded a hammer with which every programming problem should be pounded; it isn't. Use a more suitable collection and this problem will largely go away

Comment: Why do you believe your current code doesn't scale? This seems like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - what are you actually trying to accomplish? Also, what do you think you are doing with the `All` method? Have you read [its documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.all?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_All__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Boolean__)?

Comment: Yeah, using `.All` is pretty dumb, but it does allow every assignment to be made.  i'm sure there's a better way though.